# Create a "temporary" table in spark-SQL, not spark-scala?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I have loaded a table from an input file.

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
    ID INT,
    VALUE FLOAT,
    RATE  INT
...

LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH 'MYPATH' INTO TABLE MyTable;
```

Now I'd like to create a new based on this one

```
DerivedTable = 
    SELECT ID, VALUE*RATE AS Total
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE VALUE IS NOT NULL;
```

Then I'm going to use this table as a source for other tables and for outputs.

What is a correct Sql (or Hive) way to create this "temporary" table? This should work in `spark-sql`?

PS: I know how to do that in spark-shell. But that is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW DerivedTable AS (
   SELECT ID, VALUE*RATE AS Total
   FROM MyTable
   WHERE VALUE IS NOT NULL);
```